# Get all fields with search on the particular field mongo node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have two different collections, One is **users** and the second one is a **product**, I want to search product by name field and it should gives all data with the user details from the users collection.

**Code snippet:**

```
app.get('/api/searchProduct/:name', function(request, response) {
    search = request.params.name;
    product.aggregate([
        { "$project": { "supplierID": { "$toObjectId": "$supplierID" } } },
        { $lookup: {
            "localField": "supplierID",
            "from": "users",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "userDetails"
        }},

        ], function(error, data) {
            if(error) {
                return response.send(error);
            } else {
                response.status(200).json({
                    status: 'success',
                    data: data,
                })
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        })
    })
```

**Actual JSON Result:**

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "5e89b936e20452a419ccbcad",
      "supplierID": "5e89b916e20452a419ccbcac",
      "userDetails": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e89bc5ee20452a419ccbcb0",
      "supplierID": "5e89bc48e20452a419ccbcae",
      "userDetails": [
        {
          "_id": "5e89bc48e20452a419ccbcae",
          "timestamp": "2020-04-05T10:37:09.582Z",
          "name": "Mohamma Junaid Raza",
          "email": "junaidraza10896@gmail.com",
          "password": "Iamjunaidr@10896",
          "contact": "",
          "userType": "",
          "profilePhoto": "",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e89c12bf312e7a5cdfe2e9e",
      "supplierID": "5e89bc48e20452a419ccbcae",
      "userDetails": [
        {
          "_id": "5e89bc48e20452a419ccbcae",
          "timestamp": "2020-04-05T10:37:09.582Z",
          "name": "Mohamma Junaid Raza",
          "email": "junaidraza10896@gmail.com",
          "password": "Iamjunaidr@10896",
          "contact": "",
          "userType": "",
          "profilePhoto": "",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ]
    },

  ]
}
```

I want the full details(fields) of the product with a search query on the name field showing below the product data :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
app.get('/api/searchProduct/:name', function(request, response) {
    search = request.params.name;
    product.aggregate([
        {$match : {name : search}},
        { "$addFields": { "supplierID": { "$toObjectId": "$supplierID" } } },
        { $lookup: {
            "localField": "supplierID",
            "from": "users",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "userDetails"
        }},
        { "$addFields": { "supplierID": { "$toString": "$supplierID" } } }
        ], function(error, data) {
            if(error) {
                return response.send(error);
            } else {
                response.status(200).json({
                    status: 'success',
                    data: data,
                })
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        })
    })
```

**Issues :**

1. You're doing [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) as first stage which will leave only two fields converted `supplierID` & `_id` for each doc in collection. Instead  use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) which will retain all fields in doc & replace string value of `supplierID` with `ObjectId()` & vice-versa at the end.
2. You've not filtered your collection for specific doc where name matched with input, Use `$match` to filter documents.

Comment: thanks it works can you explain about the search in-case sensitive.

Comment: I have done with: { $match : {'name':{'$regex':search, '$options' : 'i'}} } thanks

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani: Ohh that case you can use regex like `{ $match : {'name': new RegExp(search, 'i')}}` in node.js, Try & let me know.. You already got answer :-) Cool anything that works !!